# How do I create a new database using Diesel?

Tags: database, sqlite, rust, rust-diesel

Is it possible to create a new database in Rust using Diesel? I can't find anything in the documentation. I am specifically interested in SQLite.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

TBH, I didn't really search in the documentation but, on the `Cargo.toml` side, you need :

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4.3", features = ["sqlite"] }
```

Inside you `.env` file, you can specify the path to the database file like :

```
DATABASE_URL=mydb.sqlite3
```

If you follow the "Getting Started" guide, then, you just need to use `SqliteConnection` instead of `PgConnection` :

```rust
use diesel::sqlite::SqliteConnection;

// ...

pub fn establish_connection() -> SqliteConnection {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you‘re looking for is not the `diesel` lib, but its corresponding CLI tool `diesel_cli`. See http://diesel.rs/guides/getting-started/ .

Comment: I wanted to create the database at run time. But actually diesel does that automatically.

Comment: @MartinEllison By how？ embedded_migration？

Comment: When you open the database,  if it doesn't exist, then sqLite creates it for you. You can run your migrations then to create your tables.

Comment: @MartinEllison oh，That may be only available for SQLite. I tried with PostgreSQL but finally came into creating the database and setting up tables with diesel_cli command: diesel setup.